# Can't open a Model

Tags: anylogic

When I try to open or create a new model I get this error from Anylogic software:

> could not initialize class com.anylogic.objectmodel.metadata.util.HideDisableValue.

Also, I got a problem with the palette:

> Plug-in com.anylogic.graphicaleditor was unable to load class com.anylogic.views.palette.GEPaletteView.

Comment: re-install anylogic

Comment: I already did but it doesn't work